# Moving Row of Data from One Sheet to Another - GoogleSheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to move a row of data from one sheet (IT Inventory) to another sheet (InventoryAllocation) based upon the trigger word "order" in the Action column. When the number goes to 0, the Action column changes to ORDER...this works:

[IT Inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCLph.png)

but I also want the entire row to move to the second sheet (InventoryAllocation) and delete it from the first sheet.

[InventoryAllocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUY9I.png)

My question is what variables/declarations am I supposed to change in the script, as I've tried various ones and keep getting the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")

This is the script I am using:

```
/**
 * Moves row of data to another spreadsheet based on criteria in column 5 to sheet with same name as the value in column 6.
*/

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;

  // The code below logs the ID for the active spreadsheet.
 Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());

  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
  var actionCol = 5;
  var nameCol = 6;

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

  // if the action/status col is changed to ok do stuff. Change "ok" below to whatever you want the trigger word to be.
  if (e.value == "ORDER" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the Skin Type column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after.  Put // in front of below row if you don't want to delete after copying to new sheet
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      // or remove // below if you want to keep but note the move, but you'll need to add // to row above if removing // from below
      //  r.setValue("Copied");
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Based upon the error it looks like you ran this function with out generating an onEdit trigger.  You say "When the number goes to 0, the Action column changes to ORDER" so I assume you have some cell formulas that are working together to change the "action column"  The problem however is that only a user action will generate an edit event.  So having a cell change it's value via some cell formula will never generate on onEdit trigger.

Comment: You cannot run this function from the code editor. It must be run by editing a cell.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hoping would happen; when the cell is edited (input of 0) then the script would run...moving the row with the edited cell to the second sheet.